# LSPCON detection error

Tags: linux, kernel, intel-graphics, slackware

I would appreciate any help regarding a LSPCON detection problem I am dealing with. A notebook (Lenovo IdeaPad S340) has i3-8145U and only integrated graphics Intel UHD 620 with HDMI output. Each of kernels that I tried (5.6.11, 5.6.14, 5.6.15) is unable to detect LSPCON properly:

```
root@wks1.S340.local:/home/matej# dmesg | grep i915
[    4.582908] i915: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    4.604103] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    4.608105] i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    4.609862] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    4.813968] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[    5.047193] [drm:lspcon_init [i915]] *ERROR* Failed to probe lspcon
[    5.047228] [drm:intel_ddi_init [i915]] *ERROR* LSPCON init failed on port C
[    5.049951] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20200114 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    5.052066] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    5.320408] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    5.351041] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
```

This is my `uname`

```
root@wks1.S340.local:/home/matej# uname -a
Linux wks1.S340.local 5.6.15 #1 SMP Wed May 27 19:56:11 -02 2020 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-8145U CPU @ 2.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

I have latest linux-firmware-20200519, and I set these boot flags, but with no success:

```
acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows 2009' pcie_aspm=off
```

I also tried turn off modesetting: `i915.modeset=0`.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that I used legacy BIOS, which as it seems, is no longer updated properly. So, what I did is that I switched to EFI and everything is running OK, even with older kernels 5.4.X. It took my half of year of patching kernels and updating BIOS to come up with this solution and I nearly switched to Windows :D Hope it helps you.